# 「春じゃもの」の「じゃもの」はどういう意味？

Tags: meaning, kanji, etymology, phrases

What does the じゃもの in 春じゃもの mean? The phrase is a koto song title, so I can't give much context. I think my teacher said it meant something like "clearly", or "the essence of". But I can't remember, and I was wondering if the じゃ was では and if the mono was 物.

Comment: じゃ is the copula (equivalent of だ) in some dialects. See [this chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ja_da_ya.png) for more details. As such, the もの here is probably the "grammatical" もの, not 物. Not sure how this could relate to "clearly" or "the essence of", though, so I don't really have a full answer for you.

Comment: じゃ *is* a slurring of では in many cases (e.g. じゃない, 飲んじゃだめ, etc.), however this particular example isn't quite that.  As senshin noted, it's being used as a straight replacement for だ in this case.

Comment: I could be mistaken about the meaning, that's what I *thought* I remembered. What is the grammatical もの?

Comment: Not necessarily true: In the word 妻{め}じゃ者 it's used as である. But.. if だ is acting as a 連体形 in that case and not like in "だもの"... well anyway see here: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/217402/m0u/

Comment: @Anthony I don't really know how to explain it... It's definition ２-１ here: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/219750/m0u/%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE/

Comment: Roughly means "Because it's spring", "It's spring, so..", etc.  I am somehow pretty sure OP has seen ～～だもん if not ～～だもの.  Former is more informal.

Comment: Just wondering, why has nobody actually written an answer as an answer... instead of in the comments section?

Comment: @Kaji The copula じゃ is from ぢゃ < であ < である rather than では.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is

> 春だもの。
>   春だもん。
>   (≒春だから。)

said in an archaic way or in [役割語-老人語](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BD%B9%E5%89%B2%E8%AA%9E#.E8.80.81.E4.BA.BA.E8.AA.9E) (or maybe in a regional dialect).