# What does じゃな mean?

Tags: words, meaning, colloquial-language, dialects, role-language

In casual speech what does *ja na* mean?

As in this example:

> 葉人をつかまえたん**じゃな**

Googling for it only turns up results for じゃない。

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17540/5010

Comment: The question still could be improved by letting us know that the OP knows that it's not "jyanai" nor a typo, and OP knows the meaning of "jyanai", and it's not "good bye" in this case. That makes this question more complete.

Comment: Is 葉人 a male given name?

Comment: @JaredMoen: There is a lot that could be done to improve this question.  Who is speaking? Are they fictional or real? Do you generally understand what the sentence means before the じゃな? (please put what you know in the question).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31759/discussion-on-question-by-jared-moen-what-does--mean).

Comment: ... or maybe you meant to type 「[犯人]{はんにん}をつかまえたんじゃな」？

Answer (score 10):

Like @himself noted, it does mean `葉人をつかまえたんだな`. While some dialects do have this change, more importantly it's used to characterise the speaker as a stereotypical wise old male (usually in anime or otherwise in a fiction).

Answer (score 6):

じゃ = だ in some dialects. So this is probably 葉人をつかまえたんだな.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `んじゃな` in:

```
葉人をつかまえたんじゃな
```

Is a localized way to say `んだ` which in turn is an everyday speech abbreviation of the actual form of `のだ` where the `の` carries an explanatory tone of the sentence based on context (i.e. the person is explaining something based on a query from a previous sentence) and the `だ` represents the positive state of being and in this case is a less formal way of saying `です`

Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.