# Understanding a line from Bleach Episode 45

Tags: anime, role-language

4:47 into the episode, Yoruichi says something that sounds like "oboe ga aru yo ja no," which translates to "It seems you recall an instance" (from the English subtitles). However, I'm having trouble interpreting the last part of this sentence. Is "ja no" a colloquial way of saying "ja nai"? If so, is she saying "覚えがあるよじゃない" and what would the literal translation be? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"oboe ga aru you ja no", means "you seem to remember."
"no" in this phrase has no negative meaning.

Comment: In that case, what does "you ja no" mean in this context?

Comment: @Ijjel (よう)だ becomes (よう)じゃ in some dialects or in the "wise old man's" way of speaking. のう is just an sentence-end particle similar to ねえ but dialectal/archaic. See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29147/5010), [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9967/5010) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23690/5010).

Comment: @Ijjel "you ja no" means just "seem" .  
"yo" means "seem".
"ja no" is the words of old man/women that means "be".

"ja no" can use in any phrase, for example,
hen ja no = it is strange.
tori ja no = it is a bird.

it won't  change its meaning by any context.